# Sort array with mutiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays

So I've made an array with the following values in it:

`array =  [[621, 685, '3'], [933, 618, '4'], [510, 392, '2'], [792, 280, '1']]`

and these values are `[x, y, number]`. What I'm trying to do it to sort this array by the `number` value in each index, so that the array will look like this:

`array =  [[792, 280, '1'], [510, 392, '2'], [621, 685, '3'], [933, 618, '4']]`

But how do I do this?

I've begun a function to make this, but I'm stuck

```py
def sortNumbers(Cubes):

    print("array = ", Cubes)
    Cubes = np.split(Cubes, [0,2])
    for x in Cubes:
        print(x)
```

Comment: `sorted(array, key=lambda x: int(x[2]))`?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks! now I get the right when I print `print("array", sorted(Cubes, key=lambda x: int(x[2])))` didn't know I could do this!

Comment: @ggorlen posted your solution in the comments

Comment: Keep in mind that the ordering between strings that are numerical and numbers is not the same. Are you trying to treat them as strings or numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope** this helped you.

```
array =  [[621, 685, '3'], [933, 618, '4'], [510, 392, '2'], [792, 280, '1']]
sorted_array = sorted(array, key=lambda kv: kv[2])
print(sorted_array)
```

**[Result]**

> [[792, 280, '1'], [510, 392, '2'], [621, 685, '3'], [933, 618, '4']]

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found something, and the code is

```
# of sublist Inplace way to sort using sort() 
def Sort(array): 

    # reverse = None (Sorts in Ascending order) 
    # key is set to sort using second element of 
    # sublist lambda has been used 
    array.sort(key = lambda x: x[2]) 
    return array 

# Driver Code 
array =  [[621, 685, '3'], [933, 618, '4'], [510, 392, '2'], [792, 280, '1']]
print(Sort(array))
```

here's a link if you wanna check more about it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-list-according-second-element-sublist/

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @ggorlen for awnsering this in the commends:

**Solution**

```py
def sortNumbers(Cubes):
    Cubes = sorted(Cubes, key=lambda x: int(x[2]))
    print("Sorted array = ", sorted(Cubes, key=lambda x: int(x[2])))

    return Cubes
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's `operator` module has a function [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) that does what you want. It creates a function that returns the Nth item (or items!) in the thing you pass to it. For example:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> third = itemgetter(2)
>>> third(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'c'
```

That makes a wonderful key function for `list.sort` or `sorted`:

```
array.sort(key=itemgetter(2))  # In-place sorting
new_array = sorted(array, key=itemgetter(2))  # Create a new list
```